# java.awt.Point class in Android

Tags: java, android, awt

I would like to change `java.awt.Point` to some similar classes that can replace this. This is a really hard problem for me, because Dalvik VM can't resolve AWT classes, but the given java algorithm uses it.
Exact error message:

> Point cannot be resolved to a type

I have also tried to import classes from java.util without success.

Comment: Replace `import java.awt.Point` with `import android.graphics.Point`

Comment: I use libgdx, so android.os.Bundle also can not resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android does not support the AWT. Neither does it support Swing.
It has it's own graphics stuff.

The class you can use instead is [android.graphics.Point](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html), when the coordinates are integers, or [android.graphics.PointF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PointF.html), when the coordinates are of type `float`.

Having looked at libGDX after your commment on your question, it doesn't seem to have a 2D point class of it's own, instead using `float x, float y` where it needs 2D points. As these are of type `float`, the `PointF` class is what you'll want to use.

Comment: I use it for a list: public List<Point> nodes;

I think, that List class is an interface for java.util. It is also imported, but the problem isn't resolved.

Comment: List<> is indeed an interface from java.util. Check the imports and see if there are still references to java.awt.Point. If that doesn't help, try making your list fully qualified: List<android.graphics.Point>.

Comment: I see, but use libgdx, so android.os.Bundle also can not resolved, so I can't import android.graphics.Point.

Comment: LibGDX won't let you import android.os.Bundle ? That sounds weird. That would make it impossible to create an Activity. Is that really how LibGDX is supposed to work? Or is it a problem on your machine? In that case it's material for a separate question.